# Transaction log shipping backup job remains after deleted database

Tags: sql, error-log, log-shipping

I have been a lurker for several years and I **think** I have a question that hasn't been answered here.

We were in the middle of some pretty intense maintenance on or SQL server last night. Or primary database mdb file was very badly fragmented. We maintain a test copy of this database for testing and proof of concept purposes.

I had setup log shipping on the test database and without thinking I deleted the test database without removing the log shipping first. I am getting error 14421 - The log shipping secondary database SERVER.database has restore threshold of 45 minutes and is out of sync. No restore was performed for 10310 minutes. Restored latency is 0 minutes. Check agent log and logshipping monitor information.

I have removed everything I could with tsql. My research leads me to believe that this error is due to the backup job still trying to operate but I cannot find this job to remove it. It's really not a big deal but the error shows up every couple of minutes in the log.

Is there anything I can do?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Log Shipping Information is stored in MSDB, not in the database itself.  All you need to do is create a new database with the same name as the deleted database.  Right click for properties, log ship tab and then uncheck the box to log ship the database.  When you click okay the jobs(on primary and secondary) will be removed.